# Need to determine when a push is sent directly to my app versus if the user taps on a notification in notification center

Tags: ios, ios8, apple-push-notifications

I need to determine if my app is receiving a push directly (when it is in the foreground) versus when the user has tapped on a push which is in the notification center thus invoking my app.

The problem is that in both cases didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: is invoked. So when this method is invoked how can the app tell under which circumstance it was invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently implement this in didReceiveRemoteNotification.  Hope it is pretty self explanatory!

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground  )
    {
        //opened from a push notification when the app was on background
    }
    else if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive  )
    {
        //push was received while inactive
    }
    else if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive  )
    {
        //push was received while in the foreground
    }
}
```

Use states as necessary.  From the [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIApplicationState)

> UIApplicationStateActive
>
> The app is running in the foreground and currently receiving events.
>
> UIApplicationStateInactive
>
> The app is running in the foreground but is not receiving events. This might happen as a result of an interruption or because the app is transitioning to or from the background.
>
> UIApplicationStateBackground
>
> The app is running in the background.

Comment: Thankyou but I don't see how this is a solution - if the app is in the background and the user clicks on a notification then the app switches to the foreground before didReceiveRemoteNotification is called. Therefore the application state is always UIApplicationStateForeground in both of the two cases I wish to distinguish.